# Entering Extended Latin characters Alt+0256-0383 in a Javascript form

Tags: javascript

Users of my Javascript data entry popup are unable to enter Extended Latin characters above 255.  For instance Alt+0321 is the Polish Ł.  Even on this StackOverflow form, I cannot key the character in but **can** copy-paste it.  Whereas ß can be keyed directly because it is Alt+0223.

Is there a way round this limitation?  Non-Javascript tools, such as MS Office, work. I'm having to advise people to do data entry in Word, then copy-paste, which is not a good look.  Gmail and Google Search seem to be similarly limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long search with no results, here's my solution:
(works for 0-65535 | 0000-ffff)

```js
var altCapture = null;

function keydown(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode;
  if(keyCode == 18) altCapture = "";
  if(altCapture != null && keyCode != 18)
    altCapture += (keyCode - 96);
}

function keyup(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 18) {
    event.target.value += String.fromCharCode(+altCapture);
  }
}

function keypress(event) {
  if(altCapture != null) {
    event.preventDefault();
    altCapture = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<input
  onkeydown  ="keydown (event)"
  onkeyup    ="keyup   (event)"
  onkeypress ="keypress(event)"
>
<input
  onkeydown  ="keydown (event)"
  onkeyup    ="keyup   (event)"
  onkeypress ="keypress(event)"
>
```

key press is executed after all key ups.
key down 18 (alt), starts capture by setting altCapture to "" from null.
key down not 18 and capturing, appends digit to altCapture.
(key down not 18 and not capturing, default.)
key up 18, appends char from code altCapture (the + converts string to number).
(key up not 18, default.)
keypress and capturing, prevent default and reset altCapture to null.
(keypress and not capturing, default.)

Comment: That works really well, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/5792509/iamoren.  I've accepted the answer.  Maybe StackOverflow would adopt it too for its own forms!

Comment: Thank you, @shawmat!
Good suggestion!
2 more reputation points and you can up-vote as well!

Comment: On my ToDo list: make it work for any element - currently: only on this (`id="input"`) specific `<input>` - for more, need to add/modify the code.
(I seldom complete any task on my ToDo list... :))

Comment: I only used Polish as an example.  The data is being crowd-sourced from all over the world writing in several languages other than their own e.g. Norwegian, French etc.  This solution allows them to do so without reconfiguring the keyboard.

Comment: Nice!  Got a job for me?
Hebrew - Israel.

Comment: I've eliminated the need for `id` by using `event.target`!